# Which Japanese animation was the first to be banned and where?

Tags: anime-history

Looking around the banned anime list on [TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BannedInChina) I noticed that there are quiet a lot of Japanese animation banned in countries outside of Japan. Me being curious as usually couldn't help but wonder.

- Which country was the first to actually ban a Japanese animation or episode and for what reason it was banned?

Comment: does this include shorts or h-anime?

Comment: @Krazer Yes, I think those can be included.

Comment: For a somewhat facetious yet correct answer, I'm sure Astro Boy was banned in North Korea the moment it came out, because North Korea was already a terrifying dystopia by 1963. I'm guessing this isn't actually what you're looking for, though, which suggests that you may want to modify your question in some way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compared to your other question [What Japanese animation was the first to be an international success?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/13078/what-japanese-animation-was-the-first-to-be-an-international-success/13126#13126), I don't think you can really pinpoint to a specific animation for being the first to be banned. All Japanese (or even all international) media was probably banned in several countries for various reasons.

- Some countries had such a tight regime that no media could get in (or out) from (or to) whatever country, as mentioned by [senshin](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/1908/senshin). *If I were better at world history I would have added some examples*
- Some countries had had a grudge against Japan and had banned all Japanese cultural import all together. For example, [South Korea had banned all Japanese media after World War II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censorship_of_Japanese_media_in_South_Korea).